# Uploading only modified parts of file to server

Tags: c#, .net, http, file-upload, ftp

I have a need to upload only modified parts of the file back to the server and merge the changes at the server.

Comment: @CharlesB IIS and Apache (if you are referring to web servers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a first option, you might want to save yourself some coding and use `rsync` or some equivalent.

If this doesn't suit your needs, an implementation of [the algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync#Algorithm) that `rsync` uses for this purpose is probably more than enough.